# Adding increased count to the DOM for every pass

Tags: javascript, jquery, count

what I'm hoping to achieve is to increase a count and then append that to the DOM on every pass through using each(). What I have at the moment is the final count added at the end. For example.

Say I have 100 divs, for every pass through it should add the new count as it counts it, like so 1,2,3,4,5,6,7... and so on. But at the moment it counts all the objects and just appends 100 at the end. Please can someone point me in the direction to where I'm going wrong?

I've added a very basic version of what I'm hoping to achieve below... also here is a [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/eronel/1/edit) (I tried jsfiddle but it seems to be down for me) .

```
$(".toCount").each(function(i){
    $("#count").text(i + 1);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input').on('click',function () {
  var len = $(".toCount").length;
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
     arr.push(i+1);
  }
  $('#count').text(arr.join());
});
```

I don't know what you mean by 1, 2, 3 ... in case that you want to count the elements step by step you can use `setInterval` function:

```
$('input').on('click',function () {
  var l = $(".toCount").length,
      $c = $('#count'),
      i = 0;
  var t = setInterval(function() {
       i++;
       $c.text(i);
       if (i === l) clearInterval(t);
  }, 10);  
});
```

http://jsbin.com/eronel/17/edit

Comment: Your second example is exactly what I'm looking for thank you!

Answer (score 1):

use [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/);

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.

in your case `text()` is replacing your div's text so u get 100 at the end ..

```
 $("#count").append(i + 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think append() is what I'm looking for but I've confused things a little bit in my description by saing the count of "1,2,3,4,5...". What I was hoping for was it to count 1, then remove it then 2, then remove that and then 3... and so on. Like a loading count. E.g 1/100.. 2/100... 3/100... 4/100.

Answer (score 1):

Use append

```
$("#count").append(i + 1);
```